# Creating a countdown timer,until a timer starts

Tags: c#

I have a timer in a console app:

```
using System.Timers;
Timer Timer = new Timer();
```

I gave it an `interval`, and it does stuff at `_timer_Elapsed` method periodically:

```
Timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
Timer.Enabled = true;

private static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

How can I create a second timer that counts down until this timer starts?

Comment: "counts down"? In what way?  It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Just create a second timer with a shorter interval (whatever you want for the counting time, like 1 second) and stop it when the _timer_Elapsed event fires.

Comment: counts down in a way, that tells the user, 5 seconds left until the first one starts,4 seconds left  until the first one starts and so on :D

Comment: How does the 2nd timer know when the first is about to start? You haven't described that behaviour.  Does the 2nd timer start the first? For that matter - why isn't the second timer called _first timer_ and vice versa because the "second timer" is the one already running

Comment: First timer starts when the app starts running,so when the first timer starts,the second one starts as well,counting down until the first timer starts...

Comment: Actually I have an idea,create a second timer, give it some interval, get the first timers interval, and everytime the second one ticks, decrease the interval...

Answer (score 0):

Create a second timer that elapses every second and use the following code to count down and a write message to the console.

```
#define COUNTDOWN_SECONDS 10

private int CountDownValue = COUNTDOWN_SECONDS;

private static void _timer2_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    WriteConsoleMessage(CountDownValue--);

    if (CountDownValue == 0)
    {
        // Stop timer2
        // Start timer1
    }
}

private static void WriteConsoleMessage(int Value)
{
    if (Value < COUNTDOWN_SECONDS)
        Console.CursorLeft = 0;  // Reset cursor to start of the line

    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} Seconds until timer starts", Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres how i did it:

```
    public static int Interval = 5000;
    public static int IntervalLeft = Interval;


            Timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            Timer.Enabled = true;
            Timer.Interval = Interval;

            CountDownTimer.Elapsed += _CountDowntimer_Elapsed;
            CountDownTimer.Enabled = true;
            CountDownTimer.Interval = 1000;
            CountDownTimer.Start();



    private static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CountDownTimer.Stop();
        Timer.Stop();

         DOES THE JOB HERE


        Timer.Start();
        CountDownTimer.Start();
        IntervalLeft = Interval;
    }


   private static void _CountDowntimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Zipper.ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
        IntervalLeft = (IntervalLeft - 1000);
        Console.Write("Starts in" + IntervalLeft/1000);
    }
```

The first timer one stops the second timer when it elapses...